# ggplot2: Use both scientific notation and full numbers

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have a `ggplot2` plot,histogram produced as follows:

```
  library("ggplot2")
  library("scales")
  df <- data.frame(test = rnorm(1000, 1000, 40000))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = test)) + geom_histogram(colour="black", fill="#FF9999")
  # set themes, axes and labels
  p <- p + theme_minimal() + theme() + xlab("Distance travelled [km]") + ylab("Count of users") 


  # transformation
  p <- p + scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) {10^x}),
                       labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))
  )

  # plot
  p
```

Output:
[image]

I used the `scales` package to display x axis labels as powers of ten, but actually, I would like to display them as decimal numbers, as long as the number is below, let's say 10^4 and 10^-4, for the below plot, this would give the following axis labels

```
100
1000
10^4
10^5
```

How can I do this within trans_format(), or is there another, better solution?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example please.

Comment: Changed my example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to branch between `identity` and `trans_format`:

```
f <- function (x) ifelse(log10(x)<4,identity(x),trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x))(x))
> f(10^(1:6))
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 100

[[3]]
[1] 1000

[[4]]
10^`4`

[[5]]
10^`5`

[[6]]
10^`6`

p + scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) {10^x}), labels=f)
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I do not understand what `trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x))(x)` does, exactly, though. Does `trans_format` return a function which is called immediately?

Comment: @wnstnsmth Yes, though it is only called through the call to `f`.